# How do I know the location a process has been called

Tags: bash, processes

I run different configuration of the same script in different folders (by strict cloning) and I would like to know if it is possible, from an external terminal, to know which is the source folder of the runing process ?

I.E.

- I run a python script from 3 folders : `pyjournal1/source/script.py`, `pyjournal2/source/script.py`, and `pyjournal3/source/script.py`
- I watch on `htop` and they all look the same "`python3 script.py`" but I can't recognize which one it is.
- `realpath` of `readlink` gives me, as you know, the path to Python, not to the "calling folder"

Any idea ?

Thanks a lot,
Edouard

Comment: `/proc/$PID/cwd` is a symlink to the working directory of process `$PID`.

Comment: A reasonably reliable way to do this is to have the script figure out where it got called from (I forget how to do this in Python right now unfortunately), and then use a module like `setproctitle` to update the process name to reflect this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First get the PID of the process :

```
$ pgrep <proccess>
```

Then you can use pwdx :

```
$ pwdx <PID>
```

The **`/proc` way** would be to inspect the `exe` link in the directory corresponding to the pid.

Let's take an example with `update-notifier`:

Find the pid, which is *15421* in this example:

```
egil@gud:~$ ps x | grep update-notifier
 2405 pts/4    S+     0:00 grep update-notifier
15421 ?        Sl     0:00 update-notifier
```

Look up the symbolic link:

```
egil@gud:~$ file /proc/15421/exe
/proc/15421/exe: symbolic link to `/usr/bin/update-notifier'
```

Credits to : https://askubuntu.com/a/49030/680673

Comment: That will only show the _present working directory_ of that process; not the path to the binary.  I think the OP might be looking for `/proc/$$/exe`'s target.

Comment: Except that for interpreted scripts, `/proc/<PID>/exe` points to the interpreter.  Unfortunately, there's no easy way to do this if the script wasn't called using an absolute path, except from inside the script itself.

Comment: Thanks you so much for such a quick and accurate answer !! `pwdx <PID>` is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Your welcome :), tick the answer right so that other users can use this reference.

Comment: Sweet, thanks for your meta-advice.